# Copy content of word document Sections

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

In my application, am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, for writing contents to a word document.

```
        var wordApplication = new Word.Application { Visible = true };
        var document = wordApplication.Documents.Add();
        document.Activate();
```

In every 1 minutes, i will write few lines to the document in a new section.
i.e, a new section will be added in word document at starting of every 5 minute and move cursor to that section, then write content.

```
        document.Sections.Add();
        wordApplication.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast);
```

After every 10 minutes, I need to run a Thread in Background and copy contents available in each sections to different text files in a remote location.

My problem is, i am not able to access individual sections.
Suggest a method to copy text in each section to separate variable or in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```cs
    System.Collections.ArrayList al = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

    int mycount = 0;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in document.Sections)

    {

        al.Insert(mycount, section.Range.Text.ToString());

        mycount++;

    }     

     mycount = 0;

     while (mycount < al.Count)

     {

        MessageBox.Show(" Section Text " + al[mycount].ToString());

       mycount++;

     }
```